# Does BroadcastChannel work on the same page?

Tags: javascript

My web page has

```
var bc = new BroadcastChannel('Consumer');

bc.onmessage = function(event) {
  alert("a");
}

bc.postMessage("hello");
```

It broadcasts a message, and the page is also required to receive the same message.

However it doesn't work. Did I miss anything?

Comment: the [specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/web-messaging.html#broadcasting-to-other-browsing-contexts) say *Sends the given message to **other** BroadcastChannel objects set up for this channel.*

Comment: @JaromandaX hmm... I need to broadcast to the current page as well as other pages.. What method should I use?

Comment: @Gqqnbig see my answer, it will broadcast too the current page and to all other pages.

Answer (score 17):

You can create two instances of *BroadcastChannel* on your page. One can act as a broadcaster for messages, the other one for receiving messages.

```
var broadcaster = new BroadcastChannel('Consumer');
var messageReceiver= new BroadcastChannel('Consumer');

messageReceiver.onmessage = function(event) {
  alert(event.data);
}

broadcaster.postMessage("hello");
```

See this in action: https://jsfiddle.net/h56d3y27/

Or wrapped in a **reusable class**:
(note: class is not supported by all browsers. See : https://caniuse.com/#search=class for browser compatibility)

```
class AllInclusiveBroadcaster {  
    constructor(listener, channelName) {
    if (!channelName) channelName = "channel";
    this.broadcaster = new BroadcastChannel(channelName);
    this.messageReceiver = new BroadcastChannel(channelName);

    this.messageReceiver.onmessage = (event) => {
        listener(event.data);
    }
    }

  postmessage(data) {
    this.broadcaster.postMessage(data);
  }
}


var broadcaster = new AllInclusiveBroadcaster((data) => alert(data));

broadcaster.postmessage("Hello BroadcastChannel");
```

See this also in action a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u567Lnb2/)

Comment: Extensively tested multiple BroadcastChannels within the same tab and it behaves as expected even alongside multiple tabs also containing multiple BroadcastChannels.  Triggered sending and closing individual instances on page load, setTimeout, setInterval, async - seems stable (all using the native Chrome implementation).  So @ThdK's answer should be the accepted one since it doesn't care what context that particular script is executing in, it can still send/receive the message.

Answer (score 1):

You could dispatch an event (call it what you like) to, say, document, with the same `data` ... then have a single handler that listens for BroadcastChannel messages and to the event name you created above

in the following, the code creates and listens for `fakeBroadcastMessage`

created a function to send both the bc message and the "local" message

```
var bc = new BroadcastChannel('Consumer');
function handleBroadcastMessage(event) {
    // do things here
}
bc.addEventHandler('message', handleBroadcastMessage);
document.addEventListener('fakeBroadcastMessage', handleBroadcastMessage);

function sendMessage(data) {
    bc.postMessage(data);
    var ev = new Event('fakeBroadcastMessage');
    ev.data = data;
    document.dispatchEvent(ev);
}

sendMessage('hello');
```

Answer (score 0):

The solutions provided by people here are very nice but the main reason that `BroadcastChannel` behaves like this, is that you can almost always refactor it without using `addEventListener`.
So in your example, instead of this:

```js
messageReceiver.onmessage = function(event) {
  alert(event.data);
}

broadcaster.postMessage("hello");
```

you can simply write:

```
const message = "hello"
broadcaster.postMessage(message);
alert(message);
```

But it also may be a little *out-of-sync* with other instances of the channel (*couple of milliseconds* I suppose) and you want it to be exactly triggered together with the rest of the listeners. In that case, you can use the second instance similar to what @ThdK mentioned.